# Blog display shows list rather than Inline/Box/Basic layout

Tags: 2013, blog

I've moved my blogs from SP2010 to SP2013, and the original **Posts** Web Part doesn't render correctly, it shows the error

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

I'm replacing this web part with the SP2013 version, but this is showing me my posts in a tabulated form, like this:

[image: How my blog looks]

When I try the `Blog Tools` -> `Change post layout` nothing happens. I cannot get the layout to be `Inline`, as I'd like it.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure first that the selected view is "Summary View".
The inline, Basic and Boxed styles work only with "Summary View"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the blogs with date image and other summary details, You need to select the view as "**Summary View**" for the webpart by "**Edit Web Part**" option. It is working as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to reactivate `BlogHomePage` feature `{E4639BB7-6E95-4E2F-B562-03B832DD4793}`. It will re-populate the homepage with new `default.aspx` with all webparts.